# Button click does't alert div contents

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I have three dynamically generated div. Each contains different data and buttons.On each button click I want to alert the data.
I have this. but it only shows the first div data for each button click.

form. this form generate dynamically

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" class="price" value=" 
{{$data->price}}"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="button1" class="btn btn-danger 
 btn-lg raised button1"/>
<div>


<script>
    $('.button1').on('click', function(){
    var id = $('.price').val();
    alert(id);
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We obviously can't help you without seeing the HTML this relates to. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: That said, I will note that you have `$('.id').val()`. The `.` is for classes. If `id` is an ID, you'd want `$("#id").val()`. More in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/), and [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Have you tried changing $('.button1') to $(this)on('click', function(){}?

Comment: Thanks. I tried with # also. But same id value for each button click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @Newbee1 - Again, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @MiksMeister I tried but still not working.

Comment: `I want to alert the data` What data?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder I have updated my question.

Comment: @Keith Data inside div

Comment: `$(this).closest("div").find("[name=price]").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
  $('button').on('click', function(){
   var id = $(this)[0].id;
   alert(id);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you told that your divs are dynamic generated, you've to bind your click event through  to another static element or document.
This should help

`$(document).on('click', '.button1' function(){
  var id = $('.id').val();
  alert(id);
});`

Comment: If so, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element and should be closed (with a comment saying how it relates, usually).